# How to compare the equality of elements in two PCollection in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam

I tried to write **Apache Beam** **K-means** using **Java API**, but I could not determine the termination condition that the new and old center of masses are equal, i.e. **PCollection is equal**.

1. I tried Object.equals but the result is shown as not equal, how can I determine that the elements in two PCollection are equal?

The code is as follows.

```
static void runWordCount(WordCountOptions options) {
        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(options);
        PCollection<Double> p1=p.apply(Create.of(1.0,2.0,3.0));
        PCollection<Double> p2=p.apply(Create.of(1.0,2.0,3.0));
        boolean flag=p1.equals(p2);//return false
 }
```

---

2. My current thinking is as follows.

2.1. read in the file as data points:

```
PCollection<String> data
```

2.2. randomly sample K data points as center of mass as side input:

```
PCollectionView<String> center
```

2.3. Assign data points to center: input `PCollection<String> data` output `PCollection KV<String center,String data>`

2.4.GroupBy PCollection `KV<String center,String data>` into `KV<String center,Iterable<String data>>`

2.5. Calculate the new center of mass and determine if it is the same as the old center of mass, using Additional outputs (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#output-tags), input `KV<center,Iterable< data>>`, output `<String center>` and `<Integer equal_flag>`. **If the old and new prime are equal, equal_flag=0, otherwise equal to 1**

2.6. **I want to use Sum to merge the data in `<Integer equal_flag>` into a single value and then determine if it is 0, thus ending the loop.**
But the problem is that I can't get the elements in the PCollection (**in Spark you can use .Collection to get the data in the RDD and judge it**), **because the merged data is still PCollection, and the conversion to PCollectionView requires me to use Dofn to access it via side input. This way I can't end the loop of the main program.**

If you have a better idea for implementing the Apache Beam K-means algorithm, please let me know, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In the Beam model, there's no direct way to get values in a `PCollection` to the main program in a runner-independent way. This is because, for any distributed runner, the actual data you are looking for will probably be in a remote worker, not in the local machine from where the job is submitted.

To compare values of two given `PCollection`s, one method might be to create `KV`s  where key and value are the same and do a [Join](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.37.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.html) operation. After that a subsequent `DoFn` could could count/filter incompatible values.

There's also a [PAssert](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.37.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/testing/PAssert.html) transform with utilities/assertions to compare `PCollection`s but that's primarily used for testing and might not be useful for your scenario.

Comment: In Spark you can return the data in the RDD through RDD.collection, in Apache Beam there is no other way to access the data except @ProcessElement in DoFn, right?

I found in debugging that the loop in my main program runs first and then goes into the content of DoFn. So how can I terminate the main program's loop by determining a certain state?

I think Apache Beam is too limited if it can't even do the logic to determine the equality of two PCollection and then terminate the loop. That is, the algorithm has converged, but the loop is still running.

Comment: The problem is that after I aggregate the PCollection into a value by join or sum operation, the PCollection is still returned, and I can't get the data in the PCollection in the normal way and break it in my main program loop.